# XML Merging using XPATH

Tags: java, xml, xpath, merge, xml-parsing

I am trying to merge two xml using 
"javax.xml.xpath.XPath".

Both source and destination xml looks as below mentioned.
**i want to append all the nodes of "bpmn:process" in the second xml to first xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"   xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" id="Definitions_1" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn">
  <bpmn:collaboration id="Collaboration_1ah989h">
    <bpmn:participant id="Participant_108if28" processRef="Process_2" />
   </bpmn:collaboration>

  <bpmn:process id="Process_1" isExecutable="false">**
   <bpmn:startEvent id="StartEvent_1">
     <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_1i0zw0x</bpmn:outgoing>
   </bpmn:startEvent>
   <bpmn:intermediateThrowEvent id="IntermediateThrowEvent_00epl00">
  <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_1i0zw0x</bpmn:incoming>
   <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_05qx4z2</bpmn:outgoing>
  </bpmn:intermediateThrowEvent>
   </bpmn:process>

 </bpmn:definitions>
```

Below is the code used to merge xml

```
Document destination= (Document) xpath.evaluate("/", new InputSource("C:/diagram_Sec.bpmn"),   XPathConstants.NODE);

NodeList listPosts = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//bpmn:process//*",new InputSource("C:/diagram_Fir.xml"), XPathConstants.NODESET);

 Element element= (Element) xpath.evaluate("//bpmn:process", destination,    XPathConstants.NODE);

 for (int i = 0; i < listPosts.getLength(); i++) {

    Node listPost = listPosts.item(i);
    Element element = (Element) listPost;

   AttributeMap map =   (AttributeMap) element.getAttributes();
   for(int j=0;j<map.getLength();j++)
    {
     element.setAttribute(map.item(j).getLocalName(), map.item(j).getNodeValue());

    }
       Node node = xml1.adoptNode(element);
       blog.appendChild(node);

 }

   DOMImplementationLS impl = (DOMImplementationLS) xml1.getImplementation();
  System.out.println(impl.createLSSerializer().writeToString(destination ));
```

The problem is, this code will consider all the child nodes of "bpmn:process" tag as seperate node and will put directly under "bpmn:process"(all the sub chidren will also come under "bpmn:process"). the output looks like this

```
<bpmn:process id="Process_1" isExecutable="false">
 //Here comes First xml nodes

  //Second XML Content after merge
 <bpmn:startEvent id="StartEvent_1">
 </bpmn:startEvent>

 **//This tag should be inside bpmn:startEvent  tag**
<bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_1i0zw0x</bpmn:outgoing>

<bpmn:intermediateThrowEvent id="IntermediateThrowEvent_00epl00">
 </bpmn:intermediateThrowEvent> 

 **//THis should be inside above bpmn:intermediateThrowEvent  tag**
<bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_1i0zw0x</bpmn:incoming>
</bpmn:process
```

But the Expected is

```
    <bpmn:process id="Process_1" isExecutable="false">
 //Here comes First xml Children

  //Second XML Content
 <bpmn:startEvent id="StartEvent_1">
   // outgoing is Inside bpmn:startEvent  tag
 **<bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_1i0zw0x</bpmn:outgoing>**
 </bpmn:startEvent>

<bpmn:intermediateThrowEvent id="IntermediateThrowEvent_00epl00">
 // Inside bpmn:intermediateThrowEvent tag
<bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_1i0zw0x</bpmn:incoming>
 </bpmn:intermediateThrowEvent> 

</bpmn:process
```

Please let me know the correct way of doing this.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show both of your xml instead of just one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath is a read-only language: you can't use it to construct new XML trees. For that you need XSLT or XQuery. Or DOM, if you really want to sink that low.

But this is so easy in XSLT that using DOM really seems a waste of effort. In XSLT you just need two template rules: the standard identity rule to copy everything unchanged, plus the rule

```
<xsl:template match="bpmn:process">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="document('second.xml')//bpmn:process"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hello Michael, Thanks for the suggestion, i will try using XSLT.